# How to transfer the value from the filter to Power Query and insert it into the query?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a report that displays data for a certain period. There are two parameters in the report: the start date and the end date. Data is displayed for the specified period. I want to dynamically load data using a filter in the report, rather than changing the parameters of the query. How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a [Direct Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-directquery-about) where it pulls in the data only when it needs it.

Note that you can have a composite model where some tables are Direct Query and others are Import.